# Firestore and cache issues? (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am running into a weird issue with firestore / Firebase.

Here is my code to fetch data from my Firestore DB:

```
firestore
    .collection("questions")
    .get()
    .then(questions => {
      console.log(questions)
    }
```

When I console.log the `questions` variable while running the web app on my local machine (localhost), it returns the following object:

```
t {im: t, pm: t, ym: t, om: undefined, bm: null, …}
    bm: null
    docs: (...)
    empty: (...)
    im: t {xT: FirebaseAppImpl, BT: t, INTERNAL: {…}, OT: t, WT: "[DEFAULT]", …}
    metadata: t {hasPendingWrites: false, fromCache: false}
    om: undefined
    pm: t {path: n, collectionGroup: null, Ve: Array(0), filters: Array(0), limit: null, …}
    query: (...)
    size: (...)
    vm: null
    ym: t {query: t, docs: t, cs: t, docChanges: Array(563), _s: t, …}
    __proto__: Object
```

However, when I console.log the same `question` variable on my live deployed production site, it returns the following object:

```
t {_firestore: t, _originalQuery: t, _snapshot: t, _cachedChanges: null, _cachedChangesIncludeMetadataChanges: null, …}
docs: (...)
empty: (...)
metadata: t {hasPendingWrites: false, fromCache: false}
query: (...)
size: (...)
_cachedChanges: null
_cachedChangesIncludeMetadataChanges: null
_firestore: t {_firebaseApp: t, _queue: t, INTERNAL: {…}, _databaseId: t, _persistenceKey: "[DEFAULT]", …}
_originalQuery: t {path: e, collectionGroup: null, explicitOrderBy: Array(0), filters: Array(0), limit: null, …}
_snapshot: t {query: t, docs: t, oldDocs: t, docChanges: Array(563), mutatedKeys: t, …}
__proto__: Object
```

Namely, the production log has a **_snapshot** variable whereas my local log has a **ym** variable. Both have the "docChanges" variable which I am using to fetch the actual documents, but I am running into issues where it works on my live site but not on my local machine (or vice versa).

Does anyone know why the same variable is returning different objects in different environments? Or how to work around this?

Comment: I answered why those object may look different below. But unfortunately we don't have enough information to be able to explain why you're seeing different behavior. For that, show the output of using the actual documented API in both cases, and where one of them is different from what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one environment you're likely running the code with access to a so-called source map, which shows that it shows the internals of the objects in a sort-of debug view. On the production environment the source maps are likely not available, which means you see the raw, minified code.

All of this doesn't matter if you keep yourself to using the documented API of the [`QuerySnapshot` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot), which is available in both environments.